# Trying to install pyreadstats in Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, error-handling, jupyter-notebook, conda

I am trying to install pyreadstat in Jupyter notebook but keep receiving the error invalid syntax. Below is my code.

```
> import numpy as np
> import pandas as pd
> conda install -c conda-forge pyreadstat
> conda install -c "conda-forge/label/cf202003" pyreadstat
```

I have tried just about everything, I can't figure it out. Below is the error.

Cell In[5], line 5
conda install -c conda-forge pyreadstat
^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Answer (score 0):

You cannot invoke conda directly from the python prompt, but you have to either invoke it in a terminal, or use the % magic in the jupyter notebook:

```
%conda install -c conda-forge pyreadstat --yes
```

The % magic will call this command on the terminal under the hood and ensures the installation is run in the right environment. You may need to restart the kernel afterwards.

In case you are working in the python console (you will recognize it because of the prompt >>>), then the magic will not work. In that case you have to exit the python console and run the conda command in the terminal.

I am not sure right now what the promt you wrote > is and therefore cannot tell if the magic will work there or not.

Comment: @Wayne Thanks, I am indeed outdated. Does it look good now?

Comment: yes, you are right. I initially did without promt and then wrote it as the question has it. I wonder why. Maybe the person who asks it working in the python console rather than jupyter without noticing? I will add the magic will not work in that scenario.

Comment: well actually the python promt is >>> not > , so I am not sure what promt is, altough the error In[5] suggests it is something with ipython under the hood